# sql pivot on multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Given the following data table

```
   Id   Code    Date                    PIVOT VALUE1    VALUE2
    1   WMAZ    2014-01-31 12:23:06.000 1     103            1
    2   EEEE    2014-01-31 11:59:15.000 2     74             2
    3   WMAZ    2014-01-31 11:59:10.000 1     3              3
    4   WMAZ    2014-01-31 11:56:55.000 2     10             4
    5   WMAZ    2014-01-31 11:56:14.000 2     96             5
    6   EEEE    2014-01-31 11:55:26.000 2     159            6
```

I need to pivot the data to get this:

```
Code Date        SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT1 SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT2 SUMVALUE2FORPIVOT1 SUMVALUE2PIVOT2
WMAZ 2014-01-31  (103+3)            (10+96)            (1+3)              (4+5)
EEEE 2014-01-31  NULL               (74+159)           NULL               (6+2)
```

How do I get a sum for value1 and value2 for each pivot grouped by Code and Date without writing a sub-query for each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,Code VARCHAR(100),
                   Date DATETIME,
                   [PIVOT] INT, 
                   VALUE1 INT,
                   VALUE2 INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'WMAZ','2014-01-31 12:23:06.000',1,103,1),
(2,'EEEE','2014-01-31 11:59:15.000',2,74,2),
(3,'WMAZ','2014-01-31 11:59:10.000',1,3,3),
(4,'WMAZ','2014-01-31 11:56:55.000',2,10,4),
(5,'WMAZ','2014-01-31 11:56:14.000',2,96,5),
(6,'EEEE','2014-01-31 11:55:26.000',2,159,6)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    tbl.Code,
    CAST(tbl.Date AS DATE) AS Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [PIVOT]=1 THEN VALUE1 ELSE NULL END) AS SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [PIVOT]=2 THEN VALUE1 ELSE NULL END) AS SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [PIVOT]=1 THEN VALUE2 ELSE NULL END) AS SUMVALUE2FORPIVOT1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [PIVOT]=2 THEN VALUE2 ELSE NULL END) AS SUMVALUE2FORPIVOT2
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY 
    tbl.Code,
    CAST(tbl.Date AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
    tbl.Code DESC
```

**Result:**

```
Code    Date          SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT1    SUMVALUE1FORPIVOT2  SUMVALUE2FORPIVOT1  SUMVALUE2PIVOT2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WMAZ    2014-01-31    106                   106                 4                   9
EEEE    2014-01-31    NULL                  233                 NULL                8
```

Comment: ya cool, I was looking for a neat PIVOT or CROSS-APPLY solution, but perhaps this is the best way...